# Installation issue with Visual Studio using Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to load up Visual Studio to write some code for mouse movement but it comes up with this error:

> The setup for this installation of Visual Studio is not complete. Please run the Visual Studio installer again.

I've tried to install everything yet it is not working... I found nothing else on the internet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Visual Studio from Unity Hub not a standalone installer from ms

in unity hub

Installs -> Add -> Select Unity Version Next -> Add Modules Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Oh Ok, Thank you so much

Comment: no worries , if it works please upvote and mark as correct

Comment: Where is it inside of Unity Hub?

Comment: Thank you! I can finally actually do this xD